# Heapsort and cache

Tags: performance, caching, heapsort

According to wikipedia, heapsort runs more quickly on computers with small or slow data caches. How could having a slow data cache improve performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is compared to merge sort.

In the same paragraph merge sort is mentioned as a competitor, in that context it means that heap sort gets faster compared to merge sort with small cache sizes.